# Setting background of IE (createPopup) popup to transparent

Tags: internet-explorer, popup, transparency

I'm creating a popup window using IE's proprietary **window.createPopup** function, and although the popup appears fine and shows the content I assign to it, I can't figure out how to get the background to be transparent.

Does anyone know how to do it? I've googled it and seen that I should apparently be setting the body's **.style.backgroundColor** to "**transparent**", but it doesn't work. Here's what I'm testing with currently, and the popup appears as a white box of 300x100 and none of the yellow background can be seen (the popup is opaque).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
<script>
var str = '<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>';
var popupObj = window.createPopup();
if(popupObj) {
    popupObj.document.body.style.border = "1px purple solid";
    popupObj.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    popupObj.document.body.innerHTML = str;
    popupObj.show(10,20,300,100,document.body);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it's not cross-browser compatible, it doesn't have to be, it's an ActiveX based project. I'm testing in IE9 but I've tried it in IE9's "IE8 mode" and it's "IE7 mode" also. Same result.

Comment: Well, the description does state that it is a popup window (  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537638(v=vs.85).aspx), so I don't think you'd be able to set the background to transparent in relation to the parent page.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the pages I'd found (amongst many others). This question was my last hope.

Comment: I feel ya.  I can't think of any workaround.  Sorry.